# Can address of const reference be different than address of referenced object?

Tags: c++, g++

I've run into trouble with code equivalent to the following:

```
const auto &const_reference = some_object;
assert(&const_reference == &some_object);
```

When I compile it with g++ -O3 flag, it doesn't pass through the assertion. When it's compiled without optimizations assertion is passed.

As far as I know, even if there are UBs in my project such situation shouldn't be possible.

Are there any circumstances when such behavior of reference is expected?

EDIT:
Link to the actual code: https://github.com/Gray0Ed/ggp_thesis/blob/67606021020546b315ad63b7fd5c2203f3e0086f/rule_engine/aligner.cpp#L177 - project is a bit messy and it's not really ready to be publicly shown, but feel free to look at it if you're curious.

EDIT2:
As RustyX pointed original code differs from the "equivalent" I've given above, check his answer to see the details.

Comment: Since both "const_reference" and "some_object" refer to the same object, the equality should always hold. This may very well be a symptom of undefined behaviour, but it's impossible to guess where. (The only other possibility is that it's a compiler bug, which is unlikely.) Start with posting some actual code and not something "equivalent".

Comment: What version of gcc? It is probably a compiler bug, My gcc thinks it is okay even with -O3.

Comment: Have you overloaded `operator &` ?

Comment: And if you have UB elsewhere, all is possible.

Comment: does the object inherits from another class?
do you perform casting since that may result in different addresses to the object...

Comment: Other possibility: `some_object` suddenly refers to a different object because it's redefined in another scope. I.e. `int i; int& ri = i; { int i; assert (&i != &ri); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will always work:

```
    const auto &const_reference = some_object;
    assert(&const_reference == &some_object);
```

The actual code that doesn't work is in fact this:

```
    const auto &oc = ai->var_infos[var_id].occurences[0];
    assert(&oc == &ai->var_infos[var_id].occurences[0]);
```

It doesn't work because you overload `operator[]`:

See MyArrays.hpp:

```
T operator[](size_t i) const {
    assert(size >= 0);
    assert(i < size && i >= 0);
    return items[i];
}
```

This returns a *copy* every time it's invoked.

It should probably be:

```
const T& operator[](size_t i) const {
    assert(size >= 0);
    assert(i < size && i >= 0);
    return items[i];
}
```

Comment: In particular, the first `[]` makes a copy because `ai` is a pointer to `const`, then the second `[]`, being called on a non-const temporary copy, returns a reference into said copy, resulting in a giant mess.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much RustyX, of course you're right. I've given you partially wrong information and you still managed to solve the problem. Shame on me.

Comment: @RustyX Do you have an idea why this expression `&ai->var_infos[var_id].occurences[0]` didn't produce "error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand"?